# VI Editor Error : Unable to open VIM Editor --> Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.1.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, vim

After Mac software updates on **MacOs Monterey** received the error while opening files in Vi Editor.

**Received the error below running on terminal:-**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.3.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vi
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

[image]
What should be done in order for Vi editor to work again?

Comment: Okay, thanks for directing me to Super User, I posted my question there.